# the point is outside or on the line perimeter?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do I calculate if a point is inside or outside the perimeter, between two points as shown in the picture?

The point A and point B have a perimeter R.

How do I know if the point C is on the perimeter? and the same formula to tell me that the point D is outside the perimeter?

if you know the answer in python that would also help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want : the distance $d$ from the point $C$ to the closest point of the segment $AB$ is not more than $r$. Now this distance is

the shortest of distance from $C$ to $A$, that is $|CA|$ and distance from $C$ to $B$, that is $|CB|$,     if the projection from $C$ to the line $AB$ falls outside the segment $AB$ and

distance from $C$ to the line $AB$ 
otherwise (this one
 you calculate with the usual formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)

Therefore : to determine if $C$ is inside or outside

1. Calculate $ d$
2. Is $d \le r$ ?

If YES, it's inside, if NO, it's outside

Obs: you may want to decide otherwise when exactly equal, that is, on the boundary, up to you.

Can you take it from here?